# How do I render DOM-dependent views in a CollectionView?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a `Marionette.CollectionView` which renders a list of `ItemView`s. During `render()`, I use the ItemView's `model` to draw some SVG using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Raphael requires that I specify a height and a width for its canvas, which I would normally grab from `this.$el`. However, `$el` (as an empty `<div>`) has no dimensions until it is added to the DOM and CSS rules are applied to it, so I need to delay rendering until I *know* that the view is in the DOM.

The problem is that `Marionette.CollectionView` doesn't add a child view to the DOM until after it has rendered. How can I override this behavior without re-implementing half of `CollectionView`?

### Sample code

```
// Renders a single object.
var ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#item-view-template",
    onRender: function() {
        var svgEl = this.$el.find("div.svg-canvas");
        // Raphael needs the element's width and height, which
        // is 0 until this.$el is in the DOM.
        var paper = Raphael(svgEl.get(0), svgEl.height(), svgEl.width());
        // ... draw some SVG...
    }
});

// Renders a collection of objects.
var ListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: ItemView,
    model: MyModel
});

// Main point of entry.
MyApp.show = function() {
    var collection = new MyCollection();
    var listView = new ListView({ collection: collection });
    MyApp.mainRegion.show(listView);
    collection.fetch();
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onRender` won't handle your needs, as this method gets called when the view has been rendered - but does not guarantee that the view has been added to the DOM yet.

To do that, you'll need an `onShow` method which will be called by the region when you show the view in the region. The problem is that the current implementation only calls `onShow` on the view you directly pass in - the collection view in this case. So you would need to implement your onShow in a way that makes it call that method on all of the collection views' children.

```
Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  // ...  

  onShow: function(){
    _.each(this.children, function(childView){
      if (childView.onShow){ childView.onShow(); }
    });
  }
});
```

That should do it. When you call `MyApp.mainRegion.show(listView)` it will call the `onShow` method of the collection view, which will then call it on the children (if it's there).

---

Per discussion in the comments, an implementation that will guarantee the `onShow` method of the child views is called, even after the `onShow` of the parent view has been called and an item is added to the collection later:

```
ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...

  onShow: function(){
    // I am guaranteed to be called from the CollectionView
    // because the CollectionView registers me in a promise
  }
});

CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    this.onShowCallbacks = new Marionette.Callbacks();
  },

  onShow: function(){
    this.onShowCallbacks.run();
  },

  appendHtml: function(cv, iv){
    cv.append(iv.el);

    // promise to run 'onShow' if it exists
    if (iv.hasOwnProperty("onShow")){
      this.onShowCallbacks.add(iv.onShow);
    }
  }
});
```

Also available in this gist: https://gist.github.com/2872526

Comment: I thought of this, but the stuff I would be doing in `onShow` makes use of the model. When the `CollectionView` is added to the region, the collection is still being fetched. I need a "render, unless you're not in the DOM yet, in which case wait until you are before proceeding" method. Perhaps I should just wait until the initial fetch completes before adding my CollectionView to the region instead...

Comment: ah, so you need a promise on your onshow methods for the child views. something that says "I guarantee the onshow method of the child view will be called, even if the child view is called after the parent has been rendered". I can whip that up for ya.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that! Great answer, thanks again for the help. :)

Comment: Should `cv.append` be `cv.$el.append`?

Comment: I'm struggling with something very similar, except I'm passing onShow in itemViewOptions and trying to get the height of each itemView's $el.

However, if I follow this exactly the height is always 0.

Comment: I want to mention that the current version now does support this event for children.